# Offsetting an array of dictionaries by a string literal

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have three variables of the same type:

```
const foo = { name: "foo", age: 12, color: "red" } as const;
const bar = { name: "bar", age: 46, color: "blue" } as const;
const baz = { name: "baz", age: 52, color: "green" } as const;
```

and I stuff these into an array like so:

```
const arr = [foo,bar,baz];
```

What I'd like to be able to do is transform this array -- based on `name` as a unique identifier -- to a dictionary where the "name" is the key. Critically I need to preserve the keys as string literal types so that I can use these properties like so:

```
const dict = arrayToDict(arr);
// `dict.foo` is a known key of `dict`
console.log(dict.foo.age);
```

Now let me start with the good news, there is a way to do this using my simple example. The following function will work:

```
export function arrayToObjectName<T extends { name: S }, S extends PropertyKey>(
  arr: readonly T[]
) {
  return arr
    .reduce((acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v.name]: v }), {} as { [V in T as V["name"]]: V });
}
```

However, this function only works because the "name" has been hardcoded in. Instead what I'm hoping for is the ability to build a generic function which takes the property you want to use as part of the function. What I tried was this:

```
function arrayToObject<S extends PropertyKey>(prop: S) {
  return <T extends { [prop]: S }>(
    arr: readonly T[]
  ) => {
    return arr
      .reduce((acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [prop]: v }), {} as { [V in T as V[S]]: V });
  };
```

Unfortunately this fails in two places. First the second function signature is not allowed (see error):

> A computed property name in a type literal must refer to an expression whose type is a literal type or a 'unique symbol' type.

and also the `V[S]` assignment in the last line fails with the error:

> Type 'V[S]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'

Now strangely enough, even though these type errors would prevent me from transpiling were I to use strict typing (which I always do), the inferred types from this function actually work!

Does anyone know how I can achieve the ambition of creating a generic function which preserves types? In the playground below you can see both functions as well as the type tests that demonstrate the results.

- [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJ9QDm)

---

I have now come up with an alternative generic implementation, this too "works" but still have one error:

```
export type Narrowable =
  string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};

function arrayToObject<
  S extends PropertyKey>(prop: S) {
  return <N extends Narrowable, T extends Record<keyof T, N> & Record<S, T[S]>>(
    arr: readonly T[]
  ) => {
    return arr.reduce(
      (acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [prop]: v }), {} as { [V in T as V[S]]: V }
    );
  };
}
```

The error is the same error as before with regards to `V[S]` but the above type ensures that S must be a `keyof T` and eliminates the first error I was getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my "alternative solution" actually was damn close but it needed a *tweak* and with the following implementation:

```
export type Narrowable =
  string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};

export function arrayToObject<S extends PropertyKey>(prop: S) {
  return <N extends Narrowable, T extends Record<keyof T, N> & Record<S, any>>(
    arr: readonly T[]
  ) => {
    return arr.reduce(
      (acc, v) => ({ ...acc, [v[prop]]: v }), {} as { [V in T as V[S]]: V }
    );
  };
}
```

this now works as expected; so the following code:

```
const foo = { name: "foo", age: 12, color: "red" } as const;
const bar = { name: "bar", age: 46, color: "blue" } as const;
const baz = { name: "baz", age: 52, color: "green" } as const;

const dict = arrayToDictionary("name")([foo,bar,baz]);
```

will result in `dict` being a strongly typed dictionary with the keys `foo`, `bar`, and `baz` and each of these keys having the full *type-literal* definitions of each object.

If anyone has a better or more compact answer I'm happy to accept theirs over mine.